# Meteor: Display random collection object on event

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am creating my first Meteor app. Simple idea: user can submit a pun (prompt and answer) on one template or view a random pun on another template. Puns are contained in the "Puns" collection. Insertions are working, but I cannot figure out how to display a random Puns object -- either (1) when the template is first rendered or (2) when user clicks the "more pun" button.

(1) Meteor - Client

```
Session.setDefault('randomPun', null);

Template.punDisplay.helpers({
  pun: function () {
    var array = Puns.find().fetch();
    var randomIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * array.length );
    var pun = array[randomIndex];
    Session.set('randomPun', pun);
  }
});

Template.displayPun.events({
  // Should load a pun when "more pun" btn is clicked.
  'click [data-action="getPun"]': function (event, template) {
    Session.set('randomPun', pun);
  }
});
```

(2) Template

```
<template name="punDisplay">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="item">take a pun</h1>
      {{#with randomPun}}
        <p class="item">{{prompt}}</p>
        <p class="item">{{answer}}</p>
      {{/with}}
    <button class="item btn" data-action="getPun">more pun</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Again, my desired outcome is that there will be a pre-loaded pun object (prompt and answer) when the user first arrives at the "displayPun" template and then react with a random pun object from Puns collection if the user clicks the "more pun" button.

Thank you and mahalo for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to initialize the random pun when the template is rendered and then update on click. The `Random.choice()` function is useful for grabbing a random member of an array.

```
function selectRandomPun(){
  var puns = Puns.find().fetch;
  Session.set('randomPun', Random.choice(puns));
}

Template.punDisplay.onCreated(selectRandomPun);

Template.punDisplay.helpers({
  randomPun: function () {
    return Session.get('randomPun');
  }
});

Template.displayPun.events({
  'click [data-action="getPun"]': selectRandomPun
});
```

Comment: btw, it would probably be good to avoid picking the same random pun twice in a row

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the advice. I implemented you solution and it works, but the Session data does not render to the template html. That is, I can access the Session through the console log and see that the correct data is there and changes with the "more pun" button, but the data is not showing up via the html handlebars.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Resolved: I used the Handlebars.registerHelper function to access the Session data. Thanks again! http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2015/02/18/meteor-read-session-variables-in-handlebars-template/

Comment: I see - you were using `{{#with randomPun}}` but your original template helper was just `pun:` - I changed the latter to match.